# java.lang.IllegalAccessError on updating Firebase Auth from version 9.6.1 to 9.8.0

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, dex

i recently updated `Firebase Auth` version in my app to `9.8.0` from `9.6.1`. However, when I run the app, it crashes instantly. I get following error in the logcat:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Interface com.google.android.gms.internal.zzanb implemented by class com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth is inaccessible (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth' appears in /data/data/com.svtech.thirdeye.thirdeye/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.google.firebase-firebase-auth-9.6.1_65404207295ac58253e1599e984563499e3fff8b-classes.dex)
      at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method)
      at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:226)
      at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:219)
      at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:338)
      at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
      at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalClassLoader$DelegateClassLoader.findClass(IncrementalClassLoader.java:90)
      at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalClassLoader.findClass(IncrementalClassLoader.java:62)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
      at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
      at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324)
      at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:285)
      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
      at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1801)
      at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1776)
      at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5427)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5000)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4940)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1549)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

What is causing this error?? How can I get rid of it???

Comment: The first line of the posted data contains the text `firebase-firebase-auth-9.6.1`.  It looks like there are still remnants of the 9.6.1 library being used in your build.  Select Build->Clean-Project from the menu bar to do a clean build.

Comment: I tried doing that. I also tried invalidating cache. Nothing works. @qbix

Comment: Have you tried [disabling Instant Run](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html#disable-ir)?

Comment: No. I will try doing that and reply..

Comment: @VaibhavAgarwal I have same problem. Have you solved the issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Disable Instant run on your Android Studio and re-run the app.
 To disable Instant Run:

1. Open the Settings or Preferences dialog.
2. Navigate to Build,
   Execution, Deployment > Instant Run.
3. Uncheck the box next to Enable Instant Run.